# Diffusion (2 species) versus advection (1 species)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, diffusion, kinetic-theory

Why do we see diffusion with 2 species but advection with a single species if both cases involve molecules spreading to increase entropy?

To take a physical example: Let's say I have a box with two equal-sized sides. Let's consider two scenarios:

1) The left side is full of gas A, the right side has both gas A and B (both sides are at equal pressure). Gas B diffuses toward the left side, against its concentration gradient, until eventually the molecules of both gases are evenly distributed.

2) Both sides are full of A, but the density of A is higher on the right side (i.e. there are more molecules of A on the right side). The higher density means (for an ideal gas) that there is a higher pressure on the right side. So the pressure gradient drives advection of A toward the left side, until eventually the molecules of A are evenly distributed.

Why do we see diffusion with 2 species but advection with 1?  Isn't it all just a matter of spreading out molecules to maximize the number of statistical micro-states in the system (to increase entropy)? What is physically different about spreading out 2 types of molecules that it manifests as diffusion whereas the spreading out of a single type of molecule manifests as advection?

In other words, if I am correct that both motions of molecules result from a desire to increase entropy, why do they appear so different?

Could it be that there is indeed diffusion in the single species case, but the diffusion coefficient is so small that we don't include a diffusion term in a continuum mass balance since it is negligible?

Comment: Advection is the net movement of species by a flowfield while diffusion is a net movement of species by a concentration difference. It has in my opinion nothing to do with the number of species.

Comment: @nluigi In my example, the flow field was created by an imbalance in the number of particles. An imbalance in particles creates a density gradient which for an ideal gas is a pressure gradient. So in both of my examples, the movement seems to originate in an imbalance in the number of particles. But in one case, it produces diffusion and the other advection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this question is different from [Why doesn't the entropy increase when two similar gases mix with each other?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218505/why-doesnt-the-entropy-increase-when-two-similar-gases-mix-with-each-other/) but my answer there is the same answer here.

For a single component mixture in equilibrium, there is no way to identify molecules as unique. So if you have a box with a divider in it, you cannot tell a left molecule from a right molecule so you cannot "track" their diffusion in any way. If you somehow made them identical except for tagging them, then you could find diffusion between left and right sides -- but they are no longer identical then.

Your intuition is correct in that a box with a single component will have "diffusion" of molecules from one side to the other. It's just that the state when that happens is completely indistinguishable from the original state. And so from a macroscopic sense, there was no diffusion.

Note also that advection and diffusion are not mutually exclusive. If you had two gasses in a box with a divider and the pressure was higher on one side, you would get flow driven by the pressure gradient in addition to diffusion of the gasses across the original interface.

Comment: Thanks. But can you explain more why there is no macroscopic diffusion in the single component case? Even if all the molecules are identical, isn't there a diffusive tendency to spread out to in space? The spread out (evenly distributed) state is different from the un-spread state, even if the particles are all the same.

Comment: @fluidsquestioner We're talking about a finite box that is closed and in equilibrium in the example. So since we started with an ideal gas assumption, the space is already filled completely by the gas. A molecule from the left will randomly walk via collisions all the way to the right eventually -- aka diffuse -- but that state is completely identical statistically to the original state and so we wouldn't say any diffusion took place. If you are looking at a gas filling a vacuum, that would not be called diffusion even with multiple species.

Comment: The other way to look at it -- translation (advection) evens out differences in kinetic non-equilibrium. Viscosity evens out differences in translational non-equilibrium. Diffusion evens out differences in composition non-equilibrium, and for a single species case there is no compositional non-equilibrium.

Comment: In the example, there are initially more particles on one side of the box than the other. So it is not in equilibrium initially. And then the particles spread out so that they are evenly distributed. And I am asking about the process by which they spread out -- which for a single species is advective, by a pressure gradient. And I ask, why isn't it diffusive also?

Comment: @fluidsquestioner For 2 species it is also advective. For 1000 species it is advective. Pressure gradients cause motion, species gradients cause motion. They are not exclusive events. But we don't "see" diffusion in a single species at a macroscopic level because we cannot tell one molecule from another molecule.

Comment: Sorry to be obtuse: if I have 3 particles on one side and 1 particle on the other, there is a tendency (on average) for one particle to move to the other side, so that I have an even distribution of 2 and 2. Why isn't this tendency diffusive? (Thanks for your help)

Comment: @fluidsquestioner Because it is advective. The one particle from the side with 3 doesn't move by the random collisions through the gas. It moves because there is a space for it to fill. This is true whether all the molecules are identical or they are all unique. Filling space (advection) is different from displacing/trading places with other molecules (diffusion). Both can happen at the same time. But we can't tell single-species self-diffusion apart because statistically the system is identical.