# Thermodynamics and Entropy problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

An isolated box is partitioned into two compartments, each containing an ideal gas of different molecular species. Assume that each compartment has the same temperature, but different no. of moles, different pressure, and different volume. The partition is suddenly removed and the system is allowed to reach equilibrium.
a) What are the final temperature and pressure?
b)What is the change in entropy?

Attempt:

a) The temperature still remains the same. I assumed that energy of the system equals the energy of individual compartment. On equating, I got the same temperature. For pressure, I used  $PV=nRT$ where temperature is still the same.
b) Since, initial and final temperature are same, I assumed that there is no change in entropy.

I would like to know if it correct or not? Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/218505/

Comment: How do you go about determining the change in entropy of a system that has transitioned between two thermodynamic equilibrium states?

Comment: So, I guess it is now dependent on final and initial volume.

Comment: I asked for the general procedure for determine the change in entropy of a system that has transitioned between two thermodynamic equilibrium states, not just for this specific problem.  See, for example, https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

Comment: The temperature stays the same, but something *has* changed.

Comment: @JonCuster This is not a duplicate of the question cited.  Different situation.