# Increase of entropy when mixing two gases

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, ideal-gas, identical-particles

I was reading my textbook and ran into this case: two ideal gases in a container are initially separated by a wall, with the same volume, the same amount (in moles), the same temperature, and the same pressure. When the wall is removed, the two gases will mix and each gas will have an entropy increase of $$
\Delta S= n R \log \left( \frac{V_f}{V_i} \right).
$$

OK. But what if we have two exact same gases? Removing the wall seems to do nothing at all to me. I'm quite confused.

Comment: You are correct. This problem has a name: Gibb’s paradox. Check out Jayne’s article on the topic. Essentially, the particle number dependence of entropy needs to be refined.

Comment: Additionally to the Jaynes article suggested by @lpz , I suggest "Yet another resolution of the Gibbs paradox: an information theory approach" by Tseng and Caticha, "The gibbs paradox" by van Kampen, and "The Gibbs Paradox and Particle Individuality" by Dieks. Lastly, I find the following very interesting: "Comment on “The Gibbs paradox and the distinguishability of identical particles [...]”" by Corti

Comment: I think what you are supposed to assume is that the gases are different.