# Giving arguments why indistinguishability is removed for high $T$ or low occupation nr. of an energy level (ideal quantum gas)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, identical-particles

The average occupation nr. of an energy level in a bosonic/fermonic gas is:

$$\langle n_i \rangle=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}\pm 1}.$$

If we make the assumption that we have a quantum gas of low density or that the temperature is high enough so that the average distance that the particle can cover without colliding with another is larger then the thermal wave length (de-Broglie wave length), then we gain the average occupation nr. of an energy level for an ideal classic gas, which is:

$$\langle n_i \rangle=e^{-\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}.$$

Initially we consider an ideal quantum gas and later on an ideal classic gas. The difference is that in an ideal quantum gas, the particles are indistinguishable in difference from an ideal classic gas.

It appears to me that once the temperature is big enough of the density is small enough, then we somehow do not care about the type of the particles from which the gas is made of.

What is the argument made, that once we make the above mentioned changes, the particles (whether bosons or fermions) from indistinguishable become distinguishable. I am assuming that this is the difference between quantum and classic gas.

And a follow up question for an ideal classic gas:

What is the characteristics/quality that helps us distinguish the particles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The difference is that in an ideal quantum gas, the particles are indistinguishable in difference from an ideal classic gas.

The particles which make up a classical ideal gas are indistinguishable too. This is the origin of the [Gibbs paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox), and of the standard factor of $1/N!$ which is added to the calculation of the [classical partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)#Partition_functions_of_subsystems).

> What is the argument made, that once we make the above mentioned changes, the particles (whether bosons or fermions) from indistinguishable become distinguishable. I am assuming that this is the difference between quantum and classic gas.
>
> And a follow up question for an ideal classic gas: What is the characteristics/quality that helps us distinguish the particles?

There is no such characteristic or quality. The difference between classical and quantum statistics is not a matter of distinguishability vs indistinguishability - it is a matter of how carefully we account for indistinguishability when we're counting the microstates.

If we have $N$ particles which all occupy different states, then there are $N!$ ways to permute them. If the particles are indistinguishable, then all of those $N!$ configurations should really be counted as one, which means that we've overcounted by a factor of $N!$ and should divide by that factor to fix the error.

However, if some of the particles are occupying the same state, then this factor is no longer correct. For example, imagine that we have three particles and three distinct states which each particle may inhabit. It's easy to see that there are $3!=6$ ways to put them all in a different state.

On the other hand, imagine that these three particles only occupy *two* states, e.g. that two particles occupy state $A$ and the other particle occupies state $B$. In this case, there are only *three* possible configurations of the system, and so dividing by $3!$ is no longer appropriate. If all of the particles occupy the *same* state, then there is only one configuration of the system and we haven't overcounted at all.

In other words, the assumption that $N!$ is the correct overcounting factor amounts to the assumption that the number of configurations in which any of the states are multiply-occupied is negligible - which is the same as saying that the average occupancy of the single-particle states is $\ll 1$.  That is,

$$\langle n_i\rangle = \frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}\pm 1} \ll 1 \implies e^{\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}\pm 1 \gg 1$$

But this is precisely the circumstance under which $e^{\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}\pm 1$ is well-approximated simply by $e^{\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}$, from which we recover the classical Boltzmann factor.

Comment: If I do not misunderstood your first paragraph, then I think it is wrong, see for example my comment with several papers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/740949/increase-of-entropy-when-mixing-two-gases). Classical identical particles are *not* indistinguishable (in the same sense as in QM). The Gibbs paradox is really misinterpreted very often; several reasons the claim made in most text books in statistical mechanics that we can avoid this with saying that particles are indistinguishable is wrong. I upvoted, tho, because the rest of this answer is very good.

Comment: See also my (perhaps not very enlightening) comments on the most upvote answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218505/why-doesnt-the-entropy-increase-when-two-similar-gases-mix-with-each-other), which however contain one or two more very interesting papers.

Comment: So actually the difference between the two types of ideal gases, has to do with whether particles can be in different energy states, or an arbitrary amount of them can occupy the same one particle state (and how many, for distinguishing between bosonic and fermionic gases). And this is how we explain the transition from quantum id. gas to classic gas? An increase in temperature, means the particles have higher prob. to be in an excited state, which translates, the prob. of having 2 particles in the same state diminishes ?

Comment: How do you recover the classical Boltzmann factor from $e^{\beta (\epsilon_i - \mu)}$? The sign in the exponent is wrong. It implies that decreasing temperature leads to increase of expectead average of the occupation number $n_i$, which in Boltzmannian distribution makes sense only for the ground state...

Comment: @JánLalinský The factor of $e^{\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}$ is in the denominator of $\langle n_i\rangle$

Comment: @J.Murray Oh I saw something different. You're right. Thanks.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I don't really understand the argument. I recognize that there is a degree of subjectivity in the definition of entropy which depends on the ability of the experimenter to effectively distinguish between individual constituents of the system (e.g. even though colloidal solids are fundamentally distinguishable, as long as our experimental capabilities cannot resolve the differences between them we can *treat* them as effectively indistinguishable in our model and produce the correct predictions). Therefore the Gibbs paradox does not require the particles to be *fundamentally* [...]

Comment: [...] indistinguishable for its resolution - only *effectively* indistinguishable. But the fact is that a collection of particles with no internal degrees of freedom **is** fundamentally indistinguishable from a QM standpoint, and therefore is certainly *effectively* indistinguishable in the sense described above.

Comment: A collection of identical *classical* particles or a collection of distinguishble particles like colloids are not indistinguishable. In principle, one could track the trajectory of each particle (although one would leave the domain of statistical mechanics/thermodynamics). And most text books just state, roughly: "Well, in QM particles are indistinguishable, so let's divide by $N!$". -No! The point is that one *can*, as usual, treat the particles as effectively indisinguishable, even tho they're not.  That is a very important and subtle point.

Comment: I agree with the rest of your comments. But again, for me the important takeaway is: a) We do not need QM to resolve the "Gibbs Paradox" and b) we treat the particles in classical stat. mech, or when dealing with in principle distinguishable particles  as indistinguishable, because in practice, they are *effectively* indistinguishable. c) The Gibbs paradox, for several reasons, is not really a paradox.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Perhaps the issue here is our definition of indistinguishable. Whether or not the particles can be tracked is immaterial; my definition of a system of indistinguishable particles is that the state of the system is invariant under the exchange of any two particles.  In such a system, the (classical!) configuration space should not be $\mathbb R^{3N}$, but rather $\mathbb R^{3N}/S_N$ where we identify points in the former space which correspond to permutation of the particle labels. You may be interested in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02727953) [...]

Comment: [...] which details this idea. If we adopt this perspective, then whether particles are *effectively* indistinguishable (due to a lack of experimental precision) or *fundamentally* indistinguishable is not particularly important - all that matters is that in our model, we identify distinct points in $\mathbb R^{3N}$ to be the same.

Comment: @TobiasFünke (a) I agree - only the notion of indistinguishability is needed. (b) That's true, but there's nothing wrong with considering fundamentally indistinguishable particles from a classical perspective as well, as detailed in the paper I linked above. (c) I think a general feature of paradoxes is that they vanish when the fundamental issues at play are understood.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated reply. Yes, I agree that it boils down to a definition of indistinguishability and I agree that it makes sense to define the corresponding configuration space like this. *However*, at least IMHO, I think it is important to appreciate that classical identical particles are, in principle, distinguishable. If you choose the configuration space as you describe, you take, correctly, into account that swapping two labels leaves the state invariant in the sense that one cannot distinguish both states (as all particles are identical). But if one follows the trajectory ...

Comment: of each particle, one can distinguish them. IIRC, this issue of permuting the labels or "physically" swapping the particles (and follow their trajectory) is discussed in length in some of Dieks' papers, including the one I've linked in my very first comment, cf. section 4.2. (although I think they give a ref. with a different view which supports your view). So to sum up, I think that choosing the configuration space like this is fine, but one *could/can* argue that by doing so you implicitly treat the particles as *effectively* indistinguishable... Anyway, thanks for the fruitful discussion.